# Algorithm to generate table from array?

Tags: reactjs

I need to create an algorithm to generate a table from an array.

Example array: data = [{name: sasha, age:13},{name: john, age: 25} etc.]

The table should be created in the way: name - one column, age - second column and the actual names and ages as column data. An array may contain more "column items"!!!

I have tried to implement it myself, but the algorithm that I have is not exactly what I need.

```
render() {
    const data = [
        {саша: 'Александра', кредит: 33},
        {саша: 'Шура', кредит: 10},
        {саша: 'Маша', кредит: 55 },
        {саша: 'Даша', кредит: 55 },
        {саша: 'Костя', кредит: 55 },
        {саша: 'Я', кредит: 55 },
        {саша: 'Короче', кредит: 55 }
    ]

    let tableTemplate;

    function makeColumns(row) {
        return <TableCell>{row.саша} {row.кредит}</TableCell>
    }

    tableTemplate = data.map((row, i) => {
        return <TableRow key={i}>{makeColumns(row)}</TableRow>
    })

    return (
        <Paper>
            <Table>
                <TableBody>
                    {tableTemplate}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </Paper>
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution.

```
render(){
  const allUsers = [
    {саша: 'Александра', кредит: 33},
    {саша: 'Шура', кредит: 10},
    {саша: 'Маша', кредит: 55 },
    {саша: 'Даша', кредит: 55 },
    {саша: 'Костя', кредит: 55 },
    {саша: 'Я', кредит: 55 },
    {саша: 'Короче', кредит: 55 },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table border="1">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                {Object.keys(allUsers[0]).map((tr, i) => (
                  <td key={i}>{tr.split("_").join(" ")}</td>
                ))}
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {allUsers.map((user, i) => (
              <tr key={i}>
                {Object.values(user).map((v, j) => (
                  <td key={j}>{v}</td>
                ))}    
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
    </div>
  );
 }
```

Here is the working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/8y2w0j95z8)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is exactly what i needed)

Comment: You should not use index as a key if you can help it: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html @SashaSedova

Comment: More detailed explanation of why you should never use index as key: https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Comment: Thank you. I got it. But in this case, I just want to give him an idea. just an example. @SakoBu

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
import React from 'react';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';

const rows = [
    { id: 1, имя: 'Александра', кредит: 33 },
    { id: 2, имя: 'Шура', кредит: 10 },
    { id: 3, имя: 'Маша', кредит: 55 },
    { id: 4, имя: 'Даша', кредит: 55 },
    { id: 5, имя: 'Костя', кредит: 55 },
    { id: 6, имя: 'Я', кредит: 55 },
    { id: 7, имя: 'Короче', кредит: 55 },
];

function App(params) {
    return (
        <Paper>
            <Table>
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align='right'>Credit</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                    {rows.map(row => (
                        <TableRow key={row.id}>
                            <TableCell component='th' scope='row'>
                                {row.имя}
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell align='right'>{row.кредит}</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    ))}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </Paper>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**Live Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wcyctd**

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is it possible to make {row.кредит} and staff like this automatic?

Comment: What do you mean by automatic?

Comment: @Spencer do you have any ideas of a better solution?

Comment: i mean what if i do not know the key? like the word "кредит' i would not know?

Comment: This data is either coming to you from the back end (API) or is hardcoded... How can you possibly not know?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Russian, but I believe this is straightforward enough anyways.

If you have a `data` array, where each entry is an object, and you can guarantee that each object has the same keys **in the same order**, you can use `Object.values` to solve this (since you mentioned it may contain more than just the two existing pieces of data).

This requires very few changes:

```
render() {
    const data = [
        {саша: 'Александра', кредит: 33},
        {саша: 'Шура', кредит: 10},
        {саша: 'Маша', кредит: 55 },
        {саша: 'Даша', кредит: 55 },
        {саша: 'Костя', кредит: 55 },
        {саша: 'Я', кредит: 55 },
        {саша: 'Короче', кредит: 55 }
    ]

    let tableTemplate;

    function makeColumns(rowData) {
        const cells = [];

        for (const value of Object.values(rowData)) {
            cells.push(
                <TableCell>{value}</TableCell>
            );
        }

        return cells;
    }

    tableTemplate = data.map((row, i) => {
        return <TableRow key={i}>{makeColumns(row)}</TableRow>
    })

    return (
        <Paper>
            <Table>
                <TableBody>
                    {tableTemplate}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </Paper>
    )
}
```

This also assumes that `TableCell` is a `td`, `TableRow` is a `tr`, and `Table` is a `table`. If you don't have these elements, the display will be incorrect.